# excel SUMIF not giving right answer

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a table with data and I am trying to do the following on another sheet. I am trying to sum the price of items in a column if the date is a particular date. I filtered all the dates using UNIQUE on the second sheet and doing a SUMIF based on those values. The problem is, the results are all slightly less than the actual value obtained by manual summation/ highlighting the relevant cells and seeing the sum on the bottom. Why is this happening? The discrepancy cannot be attributed to any single cell it is supposed to sum.

btw anyone knows why the similar questions box seems to be bugging out? The original text stays in place as I scroll, like some kind of ghost effect.

edit: here is a picture of the problem
[image]

Comment: please show some test data and the formula you use, to reproduce. see [mcve]

Comment: But from the sounds of it you can use a pivot table to do what you want

Comment: not really sure how I can do that because if I were to copy all the values to a new sheet and use the same formulas, it works out

Comment: Then the problem is with the data and not the formula.  And we cannot help with the data part.

Comment: Best guess is that you have some numbers stored as strings in the sum range and it is skipping those.

Comment: ok I managed to recreate the discrepancy, how can I share the sheet?

Comment: post it as a text data or a picture in the original question using [edit].

Comment: so I posted the picture in the question, seems like the issue is adding a row above the data?

Comment: Is H2 `=UNIQUE(F:F)`?

Comment: no just the relevant cells, 

`=SORT(UNIQUE(FILTER(F2:F31,F2:F31<>"")))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I think is the explanation.

From the documentation: *The sum_range argument does not have to be the same size and shape as the range argument. The actual cells that are added are determined by using the upper leftmost cell in the sum_range argument as the beginning cell, and then including cells that correspond in size and shape to the range argument*

Your formula:  `=SUMIF(F2:F31,"="&H2,G:G)`

thus evaluates to `=SUMIF(F2:F31,"="&H2,G1:G30)`

Because of the offset in the ranges, the last instance of `range = H2` gets dropped.  And `34.86-33.67 = 1.19` which is the last cell that should be added.

In other words, `g1` is evaluated against `f2`, and `g13` is evaluated against `f14`.  Since `f14` does not contain `3/2/2020`, the `1.19` does not get added by `SUMIF`

Sometimes this is useful. But here, as you note, it has an unwanted result.

It works in your first case because both `range` and `sum_range` start in the same row.

All you need to do to get it working in your second case is to ensure both ranges start at the same row.

eg:  `=SUMIF(F2:F31,"="&H2,G2)`  would work

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! Do you know of any instances where this is desired?

Comment: @inyrface You might use offset references if your data and criteria are all, for example, in the same row or column (alternating or with a regular pattern).